# How to fix gas issue

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain, gas, flash-loans

Contract address: 0x2138fF6dB5125F68E69152679D340c09d09eDEF0

USDC token address goerli: 0x9FD21bE27A2B059a288229361E2fA632D8D2d074

I sent USDC to the contract which I can see it when I invoke the "getBalance" function. But, when using that same USDC address that I just checked for getBalance and I invoke the "requestFlashLoan" I get the following error:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted: 27","id":2959704706602566}
```

Can Any suggest anything? Here is my code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import {FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase} from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/flashloan/base/FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase.sol";
import {IPoolAddressesProvider} from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import {IERC20} from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/IERC20.sol";

contract FlashLoan is FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase {
    address payable owner;

    constructor(address _addressProvider) FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(IPoolAddressesProvider(_addressProvider)) 
    {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function executeOperation(
        address asset,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 premium,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    ) external override returns (bool) {
        // we should have the borrowed funds by this point
        uint256 amountOwned = amount + premium;
        IERC20(asset).approve(address(POOL), amountOwned);

        return true;
    }

    function requestFlashLoan(address _token, uint256 _amount) public {

        address recieverAddress = address(this);
        address asset = _token;
        uint256 amount = _amount;
        bytes memory params = '';
        uint16 referralCode = 0;


        POOL.flashLoanSimple(
            recieverAddress,
            asset,
            amount,
            params,
            referralCode
        );
    }

    function getBalance(address _tokenAddress) external view returns(uint256) {
        return IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function withdraw(address _tokenAddress) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
        token.transfer(msg.sender, token.balanceOf(address(this)));
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner, 'Only the contract owner can call this function');
        _;
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loan **isn't taken from your contract**. Your contract only serves as an interface for the Aave's protocol ([0x7b5C526B7F8dfdff278b4a3e045083FBA4028790](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x7b5C526B7F8dfdff278b4a3e045083FBA4028790)). So the problem is that Aave's Pool address doesn't own the tokens you wish to borrow.

Maybe try looking into the Aave protocol a bit further and supply the protocol with your token before borrowing it.

Comment: Looks like ill need to have some AAVE test USDC sent to my wallet. Looks like the test USDC token contract is: 0xA2025B15a1757311bfD68cb14eaeFCc237AF5b43 I can add it to my metamask but cant seem to find where to have it sent. But thank you!

Comment: Everything is now working as expected!

Comment: Great, Im glad it helped :)